# Spring 4 with hibernate 5.2 Configuration( moving hibernate 4 to 5.2) : Failed to start the tomcat server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, tomcat

[image]

Following is the error log for this Hibernate 5 + spring 4 integration.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.social.*","com.*" })
public class HBConfig {

   @Bean
   public LocalSessionFactoryBean getSessionFactory() {
      LocalSessionFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();

      Properties props = new Properties();
      // Setting JDBC properties
      props.put(DRIVER, "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
      props.put(URL, "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/socialdev");
      props.put(USER, "root");
      props.put(PASS,"123");

      // Setting Hibernate properties
      props.put(SHOW_SQL, true);
      props.put(HBM2DDL_AUTO, "update");

      // Setting C3P0 properties
      props.put(C3P0_MIN_SIZE, 5);
      props.put(C3P0_MAX_SIZE, 20);
      props.put(C3P0_ACQUIRE_INCREMENT, 1);
      props.put(C3P0_TIMEOUT, 1800);
      props.put(C3P0_MAX_STATEMENTS, 150);

      factoryBean.setHibernateProperties(props);
      factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.social.entity");

      return factoryBean;
   }

   @Bean
   public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
      HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
      transactionManager.setSessionFactory(getSessionFactory().getObject());
      return transactionManager;
   }
```

above is the configuration. Let me know what mistake i am doing, with the same codebase hibernate 4 was  working fine to me.

Comment: please edit your question and remove your error log screenshot and copy the error log into your question.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a version mismatch problem, I had faced this while upgrading to Hibernate 5.2.

In fact there are number of threads on stackoverflow but I couldn't find the exact solution,  until I found there was issue logged with Spring to support Hibernate 5.2, you can refer the issue at  https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/18899

As far as solution is concerned

- upgrade your spring version to latest 4.3.x series ,as of today you can move to Spring **4.3.30.RELEASE**
- since You already moved to Hibernate 5.2 make sure all Hibernate artifact version are 5.2.x

This should solve your problem,

Answer (score 0):

```
  @Bean
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
  }


  @Bean
  @Primary
  public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
    return transactionManager;
  }

  @Bean
  @Primary
  public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource,
    JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter) {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lef = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    lef.setDataSource(dataSource);
    lef.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
    Properties props = new Properties();
  props.put(DRIVER, "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
  props.put(URL, "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/socialdev");
  props.put(USER, "root");
  props.put(PASS,"123");

  // Setting Hibernate properties
  props.put(SHOW_SQL, true);
  props.put(HBM2DDL_AUTO, "update");

  // Setting C3P0 properties
  props.put(C3P0_MIN_SIZE, 5);
  props.put(C3P0_MAX_SIZE, 20);
  props.put(C3P0_ACQUIRE_INCREMENT, 1);
  props.put(C3P0_TIMEOUT, 1800);
  props.put(C3P0_MAX_STATEMENTS, 150);

    props.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect");
    lef.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);
    //lef.setPersistenceProvider(new HackedHibernatePersistence());
    lef.setPackagesToScan("com.social.entity");
    lef.afterPropertiesSet();
    
    return lef.getObject();
  }
```

Comment: i am using spring4 , above configuration seem part of boot. can you suggest me solution for spring 4.

Comment: what would be the expected cause?